# Conditonal formatting after specific date

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an Excelsheet with lot of dates.
I need to highlight the rows witch will be 6 months after given date but before march 1 2020.

Column A = Date
Column B= Date + 6 months
I would like column B to give me a color red or green if the column is before or after march 1 2020.

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyNXB.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7o8H.png)

Comment: And what are you failing at? For conditional formatting, select the 'Use formula ...' option, specify the area where it will be applied, enter the formula (eg B1 <01-03-2020) and specify the formatting required. Do the same with the other condition. That's all.

Comment: Thank you, that is a simple solutions. Sometimes the simpler the easier. :-)